# Kinematics of an object placed on a treadmill

Tags: kinematics, friction

It has been quite some time since I've done even basic kinematics, as my background is in mathematics, rather than physics, and I am at embarrassed how dumbfounded I am at formulating the equations of kinematics for an object placed on a treadmill.

[image: tablecloth trick]

In this diagram, we have an object of mass $m$ placed on a surface moving at a constant velocity $v$.

> I would like to calculate the relationship here between the acceleration of the object, the velocity of the surface it's on, and friction.

For the project I am working with, we can assume there's no rotational force (or drag).

Clearly, this has a lot to do with friction. If there were no friction, then the acceleration would be zero, otherwise, the object will accelerate up to match the speed of the surface (I assume). I recall that the equation of friction is going to equal $\mu N$, where $\mu$ is the coefficient of friction, and $N$ is the normal force, which I assume simply equals $mg$. However, I can't quite figure out how this is related to the velocity of the surface this is on.

This is not so different than the kinematics of the classic tablecloth-trick. However, I can't seem to find any demonstration of such that actually dives into the mathematics behind it. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I can't quite figure out how this is related to the velocity of the surface this is on.

It's not related.  The general formula for the force due to kinetic friction is independent of the relative velocity between the objects.

In your scenario, the speed is only relevant in that once the object matches the treadmill's speed, the friction will go to zero.

You have the mathematics correct in your question.

The general form for force from kinetic friction is $F = \mu N$.  The only thing missing here is that the force will be in the opposite direction of relative motion.  If the box is moving to the left *relative to the treadmill*, then it will experience a friction force to the right.

You can then calculate the acceleration directly.
$$a = \frac Fm = \frac{\mu N}m$$
There is no velocity factor.

Comment: I see, but the object would indeed accelerate, so how is the acceleration of the object related to the (relative) velocity of the surface?

Comment: There is still static friction on the object. Do you mean that there will be no kinetic friction?

Comment: @Graviton, the acceleration is independent (not related) to the velocity of the surface.  A box dropped on a treadmill moving at $v$ and a treadmill moving at $2v$ will both accelerate at the same rate.  The only thing that matters is if the velocity of the box differs from the velocity of the treadmill.  But the magnitude of the difference is irrelevant to the acceleration.

Comment: @Tachyon, why do you think there would be non-zero static friction once the box matches the velocity of the treadmill?

Comment: Doesn't every object at rest have static friction?

Comment: @Tachyon No.  Friction can arise to oppose other forces that would be trying to impose relative motion.  But it does not have to be there.

If I put a box down in the middle of a flat table, what would the magnitude and direction of friction be after a few seconds?

Comment: I guess you are right then. Thanks for clarifying.